# Simple emscripten loop fails to run

Tags: c++, emscripten

I have the following C++ code for emscripten:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <emscripten.h>

void loop(){
    printf("loop");
}

int main() {
  printf("Hello World!");
  emscripten_set_main_loop(loop, 30, 1);
  return 1;
}
```

I then compile this with the following command:

```
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/emscripten/./emcc main.cpp -o index.html

mv index.html /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/emscripten/test/index.html
mv index.js /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/emscripten/test/index.js
```

Compilation runs just fine, but for some reason I don't get *any* output (so not even the "Hello World!").
Is there something simple I'm overlooking?

My SDK version is 1.8.2

---

EDIT

I got it to work, it seems that for some reason, printf only works if you put a newline after it.

Comment: I just had the same issue today actually; Somehow I think emscripten ignores the printf's in the loops (redirecting output?), because I couldn't get it to print either. Try draw something simple, manipulate a global variable or something else, to verify that code is actually running. If you want I have a simple [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (that worked for me) here: https://gist.github.com/Jegp/8907982

Comment: does std::cout work? Cout works for me